# Query multiple taxonomies with pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, multi-taxonomy-query

i'm query multiple taxonomies and have no problem with it but pagination is not working how to solve it, i try alot of suggestion but no success
here is my code

```
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['genre'])) {
            $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
            'showposts' => 20 ,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'anime_genre',
                'terms' => $_POST['genre'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' =>'AND'
                )
            );
        }
        query_posts($myquery);
            if (have_posts()):
                while (have_posts()):
                    the_post();
                    mystique_post();
                endwhile;
            wp_pagenavi();
            else: ?>
                <h1 class="title error"><?php _e("No posts found","mystique"); ?></h1>
                <p><?php _e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.","mystique"); ?></p>
            <?php 
            endif;
```

i have no problem with query taxonomies but only pagination is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how i managed to resolve my problem but another problem poped up,

```
    $paged = 1;
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
  $args=array(
'paged' => $paged,
'post_type'=>'animes',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'order'=>'ASC',
'posts_per_page'=>'15',
'orderby'=>'title',
'tax_query'=>array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'anime_genre',
        'terms' => array('drama','romance'),
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' =>'AND',
    ),

)
);

    print_r($args);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    //wp_reset_postdata();
    //query_posts($myquery);
    if ($loop->have_posts()){
    //while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    // output
  //        the_post();
    $loop->the_post();
    mystique_post();
    endwhile;
    //mystique_pagenavi();
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
        wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

```
    ........
    ........
    if(isset($_POST['genre'])) {
        $myquery = array(
            'showposts' => 20 ,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'anime_genre',
                    'terms' => $_POST['genre'],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' =>'AND'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    query_posts($myquery);
    ......
```